# Patch `pmatrix` with optional arguments

Tags: lyx, matrices, etoolbox, xpatch, nicematrix

I need to patch the math command `pmatrix` with optional arguments. For example, I'd like to patch the following code, while treating it as immutable.

```latex
\[
 \begin{pmatrix} 
    & a & b\\
  c & 1 & 2\\
  d & 3 & 4
 \end{pmatrix}
\]
```

The goal is supply some optional arguments to `pmatrix`, such as in `\begin{pmatrix}[first-row, first-col]{ ...`, which are required from 
[`nicematrix`](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf). So the arguments would be supplied like this:

```latex
{
\AddOptionalArgumentsHere[first-row,first-col]
\[
 \begin{pmatrix} 
    & a & b\\
  c & 1 & 2\\
  d & 3 & 4
 \end{pmatrix}
\]
}
```

Seems `etoolbox` or `xpatch` should be able to easily do this, but I'm struggling to figure it out. I guess it should be something like

```
\patchcmd{pmatrix}{}{}{}{}
```

The reason I can't just type the optional arguments into latex is because the code is generated by lyx. 
[image: lyx image]

Comment: You're using the environment form of `pmatrix`, and then request a use of `\begin{pmatrix}[...]{ ... }`... can you explain and/or correct this?

Comment: A `pmatrix` environment is just an `array` environment in disguise. Ir's probably more straightforward to apply patches to the contents of an `array` environment than to a `pmatrix` environment.

Comment: @Werner, thank you. I have updated the question with a LyX screenshot to explain why I cannot directly apply the optional arguments. Basically my hands are tied on that one, since LyX doesn't have it built in, so I need to patch the command form the outside.

Answer (score 7):

In recent versions of `nicematrix`, the key `transparent` is deprecated (because the name was ambiguous). One should use the keys `renew-dots` and `renew-matrix` instead.

---

If you want the environment `pmatrix` of `amsmath` behave as the environment `pNiceMatrix` of `nicematrix`, you should load the package `nicematrix` with the keys `renew-dots` and `renew-matrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[renew-dots,renew-matrix]{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
$\begin{pmatrix}[first-row,first-col]
  & a & b \\
x & 1 & 2 \\
y & 3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: Thank you. I loaded it with `\usepackage[renew-matrix]{nicematrix}`, which i think also redefines pmatrix. I can use `transperant` instead.  The problem is that I am typesetting using LyX, (see updated question above), which generates LaTeX code. I cannot directly add optional arguments to pmatrix in Lyx, but I can call LaTeX code directly beforehand, as shown in picture above with `\AddOptinalArgumentsHere` command. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: @AimForClarity: You can use `\NiceMatrixOptions` which sets `nicematrix` options. But  this command sets the options globally. We will have to put a `{` before `\NiceMatrixOptions` and a `}` after the matrix. However, in the current version of `nicematrix`, the options `first-row` and co are not accepted in `\NiceMatrixOptions`. But I can change that. If you are interested, send me an email and I will send a modified version for testing (you will find my address on the documentation of `nicematrix`).

Comment: Thank you, just e-mailed you